# What package do I install for GNOME Classic on a minimal install?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-minimal

Unity is not supported on my hardware, and as such I want to use GNOME Classic. What package do I install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked [`ubuntu-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-desktop) meta-package again and found `gnome-session` was the package I'm looking for.

Comment: On 11.10, Unity 2D is really good. Perhaps you might want to consider having a look at the beta? :)

Comment: @Jo-Erlend Schinstad, I already upgraded to Oneiric before beta was released. While I am impressed, I do not feel it's a complete and viable replacement (for me).

Answer (score 3):

Try `gnome-desktop-environment`. That should install unmodified Gnome2, similar to what you get in Debian.